# Recursively sort a list of nested dictionaries by value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries, themselves with nested lists of dictionaries. All of the nest levels have a similar structure, thankfully. I desire to sort these nested lists of dictionaries. I grasp the technique to sort a list of dictionaries by value. I'm struggling with the recursion that will sort the inner lists.

```
def reorder(l, sort_by):
    # I have been trying to add a recursion here
    # so that the function calls itself for each
    # nested group of "children". So far, fail
    return sorted(l, key=lambda k: k[sort_by]) 

l = [
    {   'name': 'steve',
        'children': [
            {   'name': 'sam',
                'children': [
                    {'name': 'sally'},
                    {'name': 'sabrina'}
                ]
            },
            {'name': 'sydney'},
            {'name': 'sal'}
        ]
    },
    {   'name': 'fred',
        'children': [
            {'name': 'fritz'},
            {'name': 'frank'}
        ]
    }
]

print(reorder(l, 'name'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def reorder(l, sort_by):
    l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[sort_by])
    for item in l:
        if "children" in item:
            item["children"] = reorder(item["children"], sort_by)
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you state **"I grasp the technique to sort a list of dictionaries by value"** I will post some code for recursively gathering data from another SO post I made, and leave it to you to implement your sorting technique. The code:

```
myjson = {
    'transportation': 'car',
    'address': {
        'driveway': 'yes',
        'home_address': {
            'state': 'TX',
            'city': 'Houston'}
    },
    'work_address': {
        'state': 'TX',
        'city': 'Sugarland',
        'location': 'office-tower',
        'salary': 30000}
}


def get_keys(some_dictionary, parent=None):
    for key, value in some_dictionary.items():
        if '{}.{}'.format(parent, key) not in my_list:
            my_list.append('{}.{}'.format(parent, key))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            get_keys(value, parent='{}.{}'.format(parent, key))
        else:
            pass


my_list = []
get_keys(myjson, parent='myjson')
print(my_list)
```

Is intended to retrieve all keys recursively from the json file. It outputs:

```
['myjson.address',
'myjson.address.home_address',
'myjson.address.home_address.state',
'myjson.address.home_address.city',
'myjson.address.driveway',
'myjson.transportation',
'myjson.work_address',
'myjson.work_address.state',
'myjson.work_address.salary',
'myjson.work_address.location',
'myjson.work_address.city']
```

The main thing to note is that `if isinstance(value, dict):` results in `get_keys()` being called again, hence the recursive capabilities of it (but only for nested dictionaries in this case).